# Компилятор выдает ошибку при запуске через консоль

Tags: java

Следующий код:

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PodBox p1 = new PodBox(3, 65);
        System.out.println(p1.j);
    }
}
```

Box.java:

```
    public class Box {
        int i;

        Box (int k) {
            i = k;
        }
    }

    class PodBox extends Box {
        int j;
        PodBox(int w, int q) {
            super(w);
            j = q;
        }
    }
```

При запуске через консоль (командную строку) выдает ошибку:

```
Test.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        PodBox p1 = new PodBox(3, 65);
        ^
  symbol:   class PodBox
  location: class Test
Test.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        PodBox p1 = new PodBox(3, 65);
                        ^
  symbol:   class PodBox
  location: class Test
2 errors
```

Запуская через Intellij IDEA все нормально, никаких ошибок нет.

В чем проблема, почему код не работает через консоль?

Comment: Какую именно команда используется _для запуска через консоль_?

Comment: Подозреваю используется команда `javac Test.java`  (при этом Box.class отсутствует), это и вызывает ошибку. Сначала нужно скомпилировать Box класс, а затем Test. Либо все разом скомпилировать и запустить `javac *.java && java Test`

Comment: Да, использовал javac. Файлы с расширением class и правда отсутствовали. Попробовал скомпилировать все разом используя javac *.java, все и правда сработало. После этого я попробовал удалить все файлы с расширением class и попробовать снова скомпилировать используя javac Test.java. И все сработало... никаких ошибок не выдало. Как-то странно компилятор работает. Большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: Разобрался как оно работает. Если создать объект класса который содержится в файле с таким же именем (То есть класс Box содержится в файле Box.java), то ошибки не будет и все остальные классы, которые находятся в этом файле так же преобразуются в файлы с расширением class. И уже тогда можно будет пользоваться этими классами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так получилось запустить из консоли. Использовал абсолютные пути, чтобы не перестраивать PATH, да и понятнее вроде бы так.

1. Код

**PodBox.java**

```
package boxpack;

class Box {
    int i;

    Box (int k) {
        i = k;
    }
}

public class PodBox extends Box {
    public int j;
    public PodBox(int w, int q) {
        super(w);
        j = q;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import boxpack.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PodBox p1 = new PodBox(3, 65);
        System.out.println(p1.j);
    }
}
```

2. Файлы

В какой-нибудь каталог (например, `C:\test\src\`) кладем файлы в структуре:

```
Test.java
\boxpack\PodBox.java
```

3. Компиляция классов

Находим файл `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe` (может быть разный путь в зависимости от версии JDK) и запускаем последовательно:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" "c:\test\src\boxpack\PodBox.java"
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javac.exe" -cp "c:\test\src" "c:\test\src\Test.java"
```

Получаем в каталогах файлы:

```
Test.class
Test.java
\boxpack\Box.class
\boxpack\PodBox.class
\boxpack\PodBox.java
```

4. Запуск

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" -cp "c:\test\src" "c:\test\src\Test.java"
```

Вывод:

```
65
```